What Are the Standard Keep-Out Zones Inside Launch Adapter Rings (LARs)
This is my first post here, and I’m looking for insights from experienced engineers. I am a mechanism designer for an aerospace company, currently tasked with developing a gripper to latch onto a wide variety of Launch Adapter Rings (LARs). These rings have cross sections similar to the ones shown below, which I’ve gathered from publicly available launch vehicle user guides.
Background:
LARs are typically used to connect satellites to their launch vehicles. They are held to the vehicle using clamp bands with V-groove cross sections, similar to those in vacuum system applications.
When a satellite is deployed, the clamp band releases, leaving one half of the LAR attached to the satellite.
The area inside the LAR is often mostly empty space, but satellite designers sometimes use this space for thrusters or other components.
My Question:
What is the typical minimum clearance or keep-out zone for components on the satellite near the inner perimeter of the LAR?
Why I’m Asking:
If I can confirm that there is a safe operating area within the LAR, my design can utilize the pronounced inner-diameter features of the ring, making the gripper more reliable. I’ve consulted several launch vehicle user guides, but none seem to explicitly address this specific clearance requirement.
How You Can Help:
If you have information or experience with LAR design or integration, please share your insights.
If you know of technical resources (e.g., standards, design guidelines, or interface control documents) that provide this information, I would greatly appreciate any pointers.
Thank you in advance for your help!



